# Why this application is taking so much of memory?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control

So my problem is, i created one app for my personal use which fetch the html pages from some sites and then display it in a web browser after some alteration. Every thing is working fine but what perturbed me is the memory that it is taking. After querying for 3-4 terms, memory usage reaches to approximate 300-400 mb.

Some relevant code from the app is

```
void sentenceBox_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    HtmlDocument hd;
    Word w=new Word();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        status.Text = "Processing english req..";
        if (checkInHis(queryTxt.Text))
        {
            sentenceBox.AllowNavigation = true;
            richTextBox1.Text = w.engDefinition;
            sentenceBox.DocumentText = w.engDefinition;
            status.Text = "Word found in History.DONE!";
            button1.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (w == null || w.engWordProp != queryTxt.Text)
        {
            w.engWordProp=queryTxt.Text;
            w.loadEngDefn();
            w.engDefnLoadedEvent += new Word.engDefnLoaded(w_engDefnLoadedEvent);
            return;
        }
        w.loadEngDefn();
        w.engDefnLoadedEvent += new Word.engDefnLoaded(w_engDefnLoadedEvent);
    }

    void w_engDefnLoadedEvent(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        sentenceBox.AllowNavigation = true;
        sentenceBox.DocumentText = sender.engDefinition;
        sender.engDefnLoadedEvent -= w_engDefnLoadedEvent;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void addToHistory(Word w)
    {
        status.Text = "Saving offline...";
        if (!checkInHis(w.engWordProp))
        {
        history.Add(w);
//        label1.Text = w.engWordProp + " saved in localdb. Database size: " + history.Count;

        w = null;
        }
        else
        {
//                label1.Text = w.engWordProp + " Skipped. Database size: " + history.Count;

        }
    }

    private Boolean checkInHis(string p)
    {
        status.Text = "checking offline storage...";
        foreach (Word item in history)
        {
            if (item.engWordProp == p)
            {
                status.Text = "Word found in history.";
                w = item;
                return true;
            }
        }
        status.Text = "Not found in offline database...";
        return false;
    }

    private void sentenceBox_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((WebBrowser)sender).AllowNavigation = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Enabled = false;
        status.Text = "Requesting hindi definition...";
        if (checkInHis(queryTxt.Text))
        {
            sentenceBox.AllowNavigation = true;
            sentenceBox.DocumentText = w.hindiDef;
            status.Text = "DONE!";
            button2.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (w == null || w.engWordProp != queryTxt.Text)
        {
            w.engWordProp=queryTxt.Text;
            w.loadHinDefn();
            w.HindiDefLoadedEvent += new Word.hindiDefLoaded(w_HindiDefLoadedEvent);
            return;
        }
        w.loadHinDefn();
        w.HindiDefLoadedEvent += new Word.hindiDefLoaded(w_HindiDefLoadedEvent);
    }

    void w_HindiDefLoadedEvent(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        sentenceBox.AllowNavigation = true;
        sentenceBox.DocumentText = sender.hindiDef;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        sender.HindiDefLoadedEvent -= w_HindiDefLoadedEvent;
    }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Enabled = false;
        saveWord(w);
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void saveWord(Word w)
    {
        if (w.hindiDef == "")
        {
            w.loadHinDefn();
            w.HindiDefLoadedEvent += new Word.hindiDefLoaded(w_HindiDefLoadedEventforHindiSave);
        }
        if (w.engDefinition == "")
        {
            w.loadEngDefn();
            w.engDefnLoadedEvent += new Word.engDefnLoaded(w_engDefnLoadedEventforEnglishSave);
        }
        addToHistory(w);
    }

    void w_HindiDefLoadedEventforHindiSave(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        sender.HindiDefLoadedEvent -= w_HindiDefLoadedEvent1;
        sender.HindiDefLoadedEvent -= w_HindiDefLoadedEventforHindiSave;
    }
    void w_engDefnLoadedEventforEnglishSave(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        sender.engDefnLoadedEvent -= w_engDefnLoadedEventforEnglishSave;
        sender.engDefnLoadedEvent -= w_engDefnLoadedEventforEnglishSave;
    }

    void w_HindiDefLoadedEvent1(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        saveWord(sender);
        sender.HindiDefLoadedEvent -= w_HindiDefLoadedEvent1;
    }

    void w_engDefnLoadedEvent1(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        sender.loadHinDefn();
        sender.HindiDefLoadedEvent += new Word.hindiDefLoaded(w_HindiDefLoadedEvent1);
        sender.engDefnLoadedEvent -= w_engDefnLoadedEvent1;
    }

    void initWord(String query) 
    {
        queryTxt.Text = query;
        w.engWordProp=queryTxt.Text;
        w.loadEngDefn();
        w.loadHinDefn();
        w.engDefnLoadedEvent += new Word.engDefnLoaded(w_engDefnLoadedEvent);
        w.HindiDefLoadedEvent += new Word.hindiDefLoaded(w_HindiDefLoadedEvent);
    }
```

Word class

```
    public Word(string q)
    {
        wb1 = new WebBrowser();
        wb2=new WebBrowser();
        engWord = q;
        hindiDef = "";
        engDefinition = "";
        flagE = false;
        flagH = false;
        engUrl = "http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/" + q + "?q=" + q;
        hindiUrl = "http://dict.hinkhoj.com/hindi-dictionary.php?word=" + q;
        wb1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted); ;                
        wb2.DocumentCompleted+=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    public delegate void engDefnLoaded(Word sender, EventArgs data);
    public event engDefnLoaded engDefnLoadedEvent;
    protected void onEngDefnLoadCompleated(Word sender, EventArgs data)
    {
        if (engDefnLoadedEvent!=null)
        {
            engDefnLoadedEvent(this,data);
        }
    }


    public void loadEngDefn()
    {
        if (this.engDefinition=="")
        {
  //          wb1 = new WebBrowser();
            wb1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb1.Url = new Uri(this.engUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (engDefnLoadedEvent!=null)
            {
                engDefnLoadedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

    }


    public void loadHinDefn() {
        if (this.hindiDef=="")
        {
    //        wb2 = new WebBrowser();
            wb2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb2.Url = new Uri(this.hindiUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (HindiDefLoadedEvent!=null)
            {
                HindiDefLoadedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

    }
   [NonSerialized] 
    HtmlDocument hd;

    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (((WebBrowser)sender).ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                hd = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
                if (e.Url.ToString() == this.hindiUrl)
                {
                    parsePage(hd.GetElementById("maint"), "hindi");
                    ((WebBrowser)sender).DocumentCompleted -= wb_DocumentCompleted;
                    sender = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    parsePage(hd.GetElementById("entryPageContent"), "eng");
                    ((WebBrowser)sender).DocumentCompleted -= wb_DocumentCompleted;
                    sender = null;
                }

            }                
    }

    private void parsePage(HtmlElement hd, string lan)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection he;
        if (lan == "eng")
        {
            he = hd.GetElementsByTagName("section");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in he)
            {
                this.engDefinition += item.InnerHtml + "<br>";
            }
            flagE = true;
            engDefnLoadedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            wb1 = null;
            wb1.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            he = hd.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in he)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("itemprop") == "itemListElement")
                {
                    this.hindiDef += item.GetElementsByTagName("div")[0].InnerHtml + "<br>";
                }
            }
            flagH = true;
            HindiDefLoadedEvent(this,new EventArgs());
            wb2 = null;
            wb2.Dispose();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Question: How to remove this memory leak issue ?

sample pic
[image: Memory Snap After two 4-5 queries.]

After query 25 words.

[image: DeadLock]

Comment: Have you profiled your application at all? Does the amount of memory used scale linearly with the number of queries?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to point out that just because your application uses 300 - 400 MB of memory doesn't necessarily mean that you have a memory leak. Only if the memory keeps increasing with each requested page and is never released do you have a leak.

Second, in order to diagnose the problem you need to run a memory profiler. If you are using the Premium or Ultimate edition of Visual Studio, it has a memory profile feature. If not you can use either [RedGate Memory Profile](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) (14-day free trial) or similar software.

I would also add that the most common cause for leaks in .NET is the use of events where a short lived object attaches itself as an observer/handler to an event raised by a long lived object.

Comment: unfortunately It's memory leak Because i tried my app till 1100 mb of memory usage. It keep on increasing after each query. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well in the constructor of your Word class you have the following code:

```
wb1 = new WebBrowser();
wb2=new WebBrowser();
```

The WebBrowser class does is to instantiate some of the web browsing features of your local IE version.My guess is that WebBrowser being a part of the IE it has a high memory consumption.So imagine that you instantiate 2 WebBrowser objects for each word that you have.You could use a pool system for your WebBrowser objects, but i would replace the behavior of those with an WebClient object which is disposable.

P.S. The Garbage Collector system is a fine tuned system using  `GC.Collect();` it's like using a sledgehammer on your code.

Comment: Actually i'm maintaining a global word object and each time i'm just changing the url of the global word object.

Comment: Given that you are iterating a collection of `Word` in your history, are you sure?

Comment: That's what i tought also Preston, it doesn't seem like only one global word object

Comment: `word w=new word()` i used it only once at the top of my program.

Comment: where this comes from then? foreach (Word item in history)

Comment: I can't use web client because i need a HTML Document so that i can use some predefined functions. anything else that you can suggest ?

Comment: I would go with the HttpClient class then, can you give me some examples of the predefined functions that you need?